# Do i have enough ram for the file analysis?

Tags: dataset

I have a 3GB dataset but my computer only has 4GB ram. Is it possible to run some simple analyses in R-studio (like anova, use some built in packages), etc. with that one 1GB of additional ram? 
If it is impossible to run, is there any solutions to this problem?

I want to know before anything crashes and I lose my work... 
Thanks!

Comment: If R can't do it, try dask with python, which can operate "[out-of-core](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/dask.html)", as they say.

Comment: What is a "3GB dataset"? On its own, that's a *meaningless* phrase. Is it a file that is 3GB big? Is it an R data frame that occupies 3GB of RAM?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on several factors:

- Whether your operating system is 32 or 64 bits. If its a 32-bit operating system, most certainly you will not be able to do everything at the same time in RAM.
- The version of R. There is a historic limit on vectors (and so on matrices also) length of 2^31-1. However, R 3.0.0 incorporated [long vectors](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/LongVectors.html) which allow for larger vectors.
- The specific processing you are doing and the amount of memory it uses (e.g. temporary buffers), and the memory access pattern it follows.
- The amount of time you are willing to wait. You operating system's [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) mechanisms will almost certainly enable your processing to take place, but swapping to disk may take time if your swap partition is on a magnetic drive (it may get much better if it is on an SSD drive). The amount of swap space is also relevant here in the case it is not enough to fit the needs.

Summing up...it depends.

Anyway, **what you can do to avoid losing your work** is saving your R objects to file by means of [`save`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/save.html) so that you are able to restore it later by means of [`load`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/load.html) in the case anything goes wrong. After saving your data, just launch your processing without fear, you will be able to retry as many times as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can try *ff* or *bigmemory* package to handle large datasets.